# C++ Reversing the operation of type erasure

Tags: c++, design-patterns

The example code which I write as part of this question probably will seem contrived and without much useful purpose, but that is because it is a minimal example rather than a convoluted code which doesn't convey the question succinctly.

I want to reverse the operation of type erasure. I assume there isn't a design pattern for doing this - if there is I either don't know of it or haven't realized how it can be used for this purpose.

Consider the following type-erasure.

```
class Base
{

}

template<typename T>
class Typeless : Base
{
    T data;
}
```

The purpose of this is to store base class pointers in a container.

```
std::container<Base&> container;
```

The type has been erased.

However, elsewhere in my code I want to provide static type enforcement.

```
template<typename U>
class Reference
{
    U &external_ref_to_object;

    Reference(U &ref)
        : external_ref_to_object(ref)
    {}
}

Base *p_tmp = new Typeless<int>;
container.push_back(p_tmp);
Reference<int> r(p_tmp);
```

The point here is that although `container` can contain objects of any type due to the type-erasure pattern which has been utilized, the `Reference` class should enforce the correct type to be used.

If this example is confusing, more context might be helpful. I am writing something which is not too dissimilar from a database application. `container` is basically a collection of all the data to be managed, regardless of what type the data is. (It avoids having a `container<T>` for each unique `T` as shown below.)

```
// avoid this:
std::container<int> all_integer;
std::container<float> all_floating_point;
std::container<std::string> all_text;
std::container<void*> anything_else;
```

Hence the type erasure.

The purpose of "getting the type back again" is to enforce all database columns to contain objects of the same type.

```
DBColumn<int> my_column_contains_int_type_data;
my_column_contains_int_type_data.insert(42);
```

PS: Try not to be distracted by the fact this code clearly does not compile. It is intended to be a sketch to demonstrate the question.

As a final comment, it occurred to me that this is vaguely similar to a factory pattern. (Although not quite the same.) We already have the object. We don't need to clone it, only store a reference to it. We don't need to load anything from user input, network, disk or other external source. So it isn't a creational factory and it isn't a clone factory either.

Factories can use some form of centrally managed and generated unique id's to indicate what type an object is. For example, one might save and load from disk data with an identifier in the header which indicates what type of object is represented by the data on disk and therefore how an object should be created dynamically.

In my case, it would be possible to have such an identifier for each derived class (each unique `T` in `Typeless<T>`) however this doesn't seem like a particularly good solution, as I fear I may write the following block of code.

```
class DBColumn<T>
if(identifier == "INT")
{
    if(typeof(T) is int)
    {
        // good
    }
    else
    {
        throw "BAD"; // bad
    }
}
else if(...) // repeat for each of int, float, double, std::string, etc
```

Hopefully the question is fairly clear?

Comment: You have to cast back (`static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`).

Comment: can you use a `std::variant` consisting of all of your target types?

Comment: I don't see any relations to type erasure here. As its name implies, some part of 
static type info is lost, so that values of incompatible types can be seved at compile-time; but some type information is stored alonside every object, to reflect its required aspects type at runtime. This post is not yet clear to me.

Comment: @Red.Wave Pointers or references to type `Base` can point to any subtype of `Base` which includes `Typeless<T>`. Since `Typeless<T>` contains a `T` object, the type of T has been erased in references to `Base`. That is type erasure. I have not explicitly written any operations which can be performed with the type `Typeless<T>`, but a full implementation would include these, otherwise there is nothing "functional" about `Typeless<T>` objects. They don't currently do anything. Hope that clears up your confusion.

Comment: Aparrt from base - which could mean a lot of things like a mere abstract base - all your declarations contain the static type of their target; that's why I still cannot see were you erased the type. From the point on -where you erase it - the type shall statically become unavailable; all you can do is a lucky guess and test `bool guess=erasure.holds<T>();`.  Check the docs on `std::any` and `std::variant`. Then please clarify what you mean by 'getting type back'.

Comment: @Red.Wave "Getting the type back" means that `DBColumn<T>::insert(T&)` should raise a compiler error if `T!=T`, where the first `T` means the type in `DBColumn<T>` and the second `T` means the type in `insert(T&)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate identifier, you can simply `if (typeof` all the possible types.

```
if(typeof(T) is Typeless<int>)
    doIntColumnThing(static_cast<Typeless<int>>(T));
else if(typeof(T) is Typeless<float>)
    doFloatColumnThing(static_cast<Typeless<float>>(T));
else if(typeof(T) is Typeless<double>)
    doDoubleColumnThing(static_cast<Typeless<double>>(T));
else if(typeof(T) is Typeless<std::string>)
    doDoubleColumnThing(static_cast<Typeless<std::string>>(T));
```

(or you can generate fancy template metamagic that makes it pretty, but fundamentally does the same thing)

The better design is usually to instead keep them separate from the beginning:

```
DBColumn<Typeless<int>> my_column_1;
DBColumn<Typeless<std::string>> my_column_2;
std::vector<Base> all_cells;

void add_column_2(Typeless<std::string>& cell) {
    my_column_2.add(cell);
    all_cells.add(cell);
}
```

The best answer is usually to put all your operations in the interface, but I assume you've already made a design where that's impossible.  I would highly recommend redesigning it so that you can do this way, but I assume you won't.

```
class Base
{
    virtual void doColumnThing();
}

template<typename T>
class Typeless : Base
{
    T data;
    void doColumThing() { 
        doColumnThing(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern for this, the command pattern. One stated purpose is for occasions when "undo" operations might be needed. The idea is to encapsulate all the information needed for an action to be performed and undone so it doesn't rely on a particular point in the program flow.

I know this is a Java page but it explains the concept pretty clearly:
https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/command/

To add, the GoF recommendation for undo is to store any original state information that may change as a result of the action in the command object. In this way the command object knows how to perform the action in both directions and has all the info necessary to return the receiver to its original state. So it's nicely decoupled from the 'Invoker' class.

If the info is complex, you could have another object for that state info to keep things from getting clogged up in the command itself.

In your case that might well include the type info, or some other method to restore the correct original type if that's possible.

Comment: Would a command object contain some kind of tag to describe what type of object was contained inside a pointer/reference to a `Base` object which I am assuming would also be contained inside the command object?

Comment: Yes, very possibly, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) in combination with `static_cast`? That is what the implementation of [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) does.

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
protected:
    virtual ~Base(){}
public:
    virtual std::type_info const& type_info() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Typeless : public Base
{
    T data;

    std::type_info const& type_info() const override {
        return typeid(T);
    }
};

template <typename T>
bool erases(Base const& typeless){
    return typeless.type_info() == typeid(T);
}

template <typename T>
T cast(Base const& typeless){
    if (!erases<T>(typeless)){
        throw std::logic_error("Or some other kind of error handling");
    }
    return static_cast<Typeless<T> const&>(typeless).data;
}

template<typename U>
class Reference
{
    U &external_ref_to_object;
public:
    Reference(U &ref)
        : external_ref_to_object(ref)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> container;
    Base *p_tmp = new Typeless<int>;
    container.push_back(p_tmp);

    int undone = cast<int>(*p_tmp);
    Reference<int> r(undone);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EhYeTcsnx

If you can use C++17 you can just use `std::any` instead of rolling out your own type erasure system.

Answer (score -1):

There is a really easy solution to this problem. It seems obvious when you see it.

If you want to "enforce" the type of something, you need to use a type.

In other words: If you want to use a type system you need a type to work with.

`Typeless` is a type, but we are using it as a single type to contain all other possible types for type erasure. To build it requires quite a clever design.

In contrast, to do the reverse is trivial because the C++ language already gives us the tools natively for creating types. It doesn't give us native tools for type erasure.

To create a new type:

```
class IntType
{
    Typeless<int> intData;
};

class FloatType
{
    Typeless<float> floatType;
};
```

With the above, we created two different types. We will need a new class for every possible type we want, unless we do something more complex with compile time type-checking. (eg: Something like `std::enable_if` with a set of allowed types.)

Using the above, we can re-associate the type with the type-erased object.

When I have more time I will revise my question and answer to make both a bit more clear/consistent.

Comment: `Typeless` is *not* a type, it is a *template* for types. You *already have* different types `Typeless<int>` and `Typeless<float>` etc. and there is nothing gained by doing this over the other answers except a few saved keystrokes.

Comment: @HTNW I can see why you would come to that conclusion. There's some information missing from the question, which I developed in the 6 months since I wrote it. I will try and update it this weekend